# y value is overlapped by yellow box regions that I have defined in chart js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

Currently, when the data points lie within the box region demarcated by the Lower Specification Limit (LSL) and Lower Control Limit (LCL), they are overlapping with the yellow shaded area that represents this region, despite the fact that I've used the "z" attribute for layer ordering and set the position to relative. This behavior is contrary to my intention of having these data points appear above the region's shading.

To resolve this issue, I'm seeking effective debugging strategies and potential solutions that can help rectify this layering problem. Any insights or advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated.
"chart.js": "^4.2.1",
"chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^3.0.0",
"chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^2.2.1",
"chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^2.0.1",
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MSR5.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@mui/material/Fade';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  TimeScale,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';

ChartJS.register(
  TimeScale,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  annotationPlugin,
  zoomPlugin
);

const SMMSChart = ({ className, chartDataArray }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedChart, setSelectedChart] = useState(null);

  const handleOpen = (chart) => {
    setSelectedChart(chart);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('chartDataArray:', chartDataArray);

    const chartData = chartDataArray.flat().map((chartData) => {
      console.log('chartData:', chartData);

      const dataset = {
        label: `${chartData.LineLane} - ${chartData.Title}`,
        data: chartData.Yvalue.map((value, index) => ({
          x: new Date(chartData.Xvalue[index]),
          y: value,
        })),

        position: 'relative',
          zIndex: 2,

        // borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        borderColor: 'black',
        // backgroundColor: 'red',
        // fill: false,
        // position: 'absolute',
        // borderWidth: 5,



        // zIndex: '999999 !important',
      };

      const dateArray = chartData.Xvalue.map((value) => new Date(value));
      const xMin = new Date(Math.min(...dateArray));
      const xMax = new Date(Math.max(...dateArray));

      const annotations = [


    
        
        {
          type: 'box',
          xScaleID: 'x',
          yScaleID: 'y',
          xMin: xMin,
          xMax: xMax,
          position: 'relative',
          zIndex: -1,
          yMin: chartData.UCL,
          yMax: chartData.USL,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 143, 0, 0.7)', // yellow color
          
          borderWidth: 0,
        },

        {
          type: 'box',
          xScaleID: 'x',
          yScaleID: 'y',
          xMin: xMin,
          xMax: xMax,
          position: 'relative',
          zIndex: -1,
          yMin: chartData.LSL,
          yMax: chartData.LCL,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 143, 0, 0.7)', // yellow color
          borderWidth: 0,
        },
        {
          type: 'box',
          xScaleID: 'x',
          yScaleID: 'y',
          xMin: xMin,
          xMax: xMax,
          yMin: chartData.LCL,
          yMax: chartData.LSL,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          zIndex: -1, // lower z index than other annotations
          borderWidth: 0,
        },


        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y',
          value: 0,
          position: 'relative',
         
          borderColor: 'black',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [10, 5],
          label: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            display: true,
            position: 'start',
          },
        },

        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y',
          value: chartData.UCL,
        
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [10, 5],
          label: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            content: 'UCL',
            display: true,
            position: 'start',
            yAdjust: -10,
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y',
          value: chartData.LCL,
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 2,
          
         
          borderDash: [10, 5],
          label: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            content: 'LCL',
            display: true,
            position: 'start',
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y',
          
          
          value: chartData.USL,
          borderColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [10, 5],
          label: {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            content: 'USL',
            display: true,
            position: 'start',
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'horizontal',
          scaleID: 'y',
        
        
          value: chartData.LSL,
          borderColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [10, 5],
          label: {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            content: 'LSL',
            display: true,
            position: 'start',
          },
        },
      ];

      // Add point annotations for exceeding values
      for (let i = 0; i < chartData.Yvalue.length; i++) {
        if (
          chartData.Yvalue[i] >= chartData.USL ||
          chartData.Yvalue[i] >= chartData.UCL ||
          chartData.Yvalue[i] <= chartData.LSL ||
          chartData.Yvalue[i] <= chartData.LCL
        ) {

          
          annotations.push({
            type: 'point',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
            scaleID: 'y',
            radius: 7,
            xValue: new Date(chartData.Xvalue[i]),
            yValue: chartData.Yvalue[i],
            position: 'relative',
            zIndex: 1000,
  
          });
        }
      }
      

      return { dataset, annotations };
    });
    console.log('Processed chartData:', chartData);
    setData(chartData);
    }, [chartDataArray]);
   

     if (!chartDataArray || chartDataArray.length === 0) {
            return <p>Loading chart...</p>;
          }
        
          const options = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                  parser: 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm',
                  tooltipFormat: 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm',
                },
                ticks: {
                  autoSkip: true,
                  maxTicksLimit: 20,
                  callback: function (value, index, values) {
                    return format(new Date(value), 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
                  },
                  maxRotation: 90,
                  minRotation: 90,
                },
                grid: {
                  drawBorder: true,
                  drawOnChartArea: false,
                },
              },
              y: {
                grid: {
                  drawBorder: true,
                  drawOnChartArea: false,
                },
              },
            },
        
        
            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: false,
                position: 'top',
              },
              title: {
                display: false,
              },
              // annotation: {
              //   annotations: [],
              // },
        
              annotation: {
                annotations: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    mode: 'horizontal',
                    scaleID: 'y',
                    value: 22, // The y-value where you want the line to be drawn
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    label: {
                        backgroundColor: 'black',
                        content: 'Line over Box',
                        enabled: true,
                    },
                    z: 999 // Set a high value to bring the line above the data
                }]
            }
            },
            elements: {
              line: {
                borderWidth: 1,
              },
            },
        
        
        
          };
    
      return (
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div className={className}>
              {data.map((d, index) => (
                <div key={index} style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
                  <Line
                    data={{
                      datasets: [d.dataset],
                    }}
                    options={{
                      ...options,
                      plugins: {
                        ...options.plugins,
                        title: {
                          display: true,
                          text: d.dataset.label,
                        },
                        annotation: {
                          annotations: d.annotations,
                        },
                      },
                    }}
                    onClick={() => handleOpen(d)}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Modal
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            closeAfterTransition
            BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
            BackdropProps={{
              timeout: 500,
            }}
          >
            <Fade in={open}>
              <div
                style={{
                  height: '80%',
                  width: '80%',
                  margin: 'auto',
                  position: 'fixed',
                  top: '10%',
                  left: '10%',
                  background: '#fff',
                  border: '2px solid #000',
                  overflow: 'auto',
                  borderRadius: '10px',
                }}
              >
                {selectedChart && (
                  <Line
                    data={{
                      datasets: [selectedChart.dataset],
                    }}
                    options={{
                      ...options,
                      plugins: {
                        ...options.plugins,
                        title: {
                          display: true,
                          text: selectedChart.dataset.label,
                        },
                        annotation: {
                          annotations: selectedChart.annotations,
                        },
                      },
                      maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    }}
                    style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            </Fade>
          </Modal>
        </Grid>
      );
    };
    
    export default SMMSChart;
```

Comment: There is no `zIndex` property in chart.js; also there is no `position: 'relative'` in chart.js. Chart.js renders the datasets on canvas in the order they are included in the `datasets` array; that order can be altered using the [`order` property](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#dataset-configuration).

Comment: The order in which annotations are rendered in relation to datasets  and axes is described by the [`drawTime` property](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/options.html#draw-time) and in relation to one another, if two annotation have the same `drawTime`, by the [`z` property](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/box.html#general)